# DbContextOptionBuilder does not contain a definition for UseSqlServer - VS 2017 / VS for Mac

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, .net-core

Yesterday I wrote a little code, which is connecting to local database (SQL Server) and write one table's item count to console in VS 2017 (last updated yesterday).

I would like to host an api in .net core from my IMac (Docker + SQL Server in Docker), so I loaded the project into VS for Mac (last updated yesterday).

When I'm running the program in debug mode, without breakpoints, it's throwing an Internal Error Exception. When I'm create a new breakpoint here:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("server=localhost;database=mra_ss_db;user id=sa;password=MYPASSWORD;");
    }
}
```

It said:

> DbContextOptionBuilder does not contain a definition for UseSqlServer

In VS 2017 on Windows, everything is working fine.

**I found lot of "solution" for this error, but nothing was useful. (Microsoft.EntityFrameWorkCore usings, references, etc.)**

> Should I use VS Code on my IMac, instead of VS 2017 for Mac?

Here is my full dBContext code:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata;

namespace MRA.DataAccessLayer_Core.Models
{
public partial class mra_ss_dbContext : DbContext
{
    public mra_ss_dbContext()
    {
    }

    public mra_ss_dbContext(DbContextOptions<mra_ss_dbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Companies> Companies { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Countries> Countries { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Genres> Genres { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Languages> Languages { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Movies> Movies { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<MoviesCompanies> MoviesCompanies { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<MoviesCountries> MoviesCountries { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<MoviesGenres> MoviesGenres { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<MoviesLanguages> MoviesLanguages { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("server=localhost;database=mra_ss_db;user id=sa;password=MYPASSWORD;");
        }
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Companies>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.CompanyId);

            entity.Property(e => e.CompanyId)
                .HasColumnName("CompanyID")
                .ValueGeneratedNever();

            entity.Property(e => e.LogoPath)
                .IsRequired()
                .IsUnicode(false);

            entity.Property(e => e.Name)
                .IsRequired()
                .IsUnicode(false);

            entity.Property(e => e.OriginCountry)
                .IsRequired()
                .IsUnicode(false);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Countries>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.Iso31661);

            entity.Property(e => e.Iso31661)
                .HasColumnName("Iso_3166_1")
                .HasMaxLength(50)
                .IsUnicode(false)
                .ValueGeneratedNever();

            entity.Property(e => e.Name)
                .IsRequired()
                .IsUnicode(false);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Genres>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.GenreId);

            entity.Property(e => e.GenreId)
                .HasColumnName("GenreID")
                .ValueGeneratedNever();

            entity.Property(e => e.Name)
                .IsRequired()
                .IsUnicode(false);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Languages>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.Iso6391);

            entity.Property(e => e.Iso6391)
                .HasColumnName("Iso_639_1")
                .HasMaxLength(50)
                .IsUnicode(false)
                .ValueGeneratedNever();

            entity.Property(e => e.Name)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(50)
                .IsUnicode(false);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Movies>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.MovieId);

            entity.Property(e => e.MovieId)
                .HasColumnName("MovieID")
                .ValueGeneratedNever();

            entity.Property(e => e.BackdropPath).IsUnicode(false);

            entity.Property(e => e.ImdbId)
                .HasColumnName("ImdbID")
                .IsUnicode(false);

            entity.Property(e => e.OriginalLanguage)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(50)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            entity.Property(e => e.OriginalTitle)
                .IsRequired()
                .IsUnicode(false);

            entity.Property(e => e.Overview).IsUnicode(false);

            entity.Property(e => e.PosterPath).IsUnicode(false);

            entity.Property(e => e.ReleaseDate).HasColumnType("datetime");

            entity.Property(e => e.Status)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(50)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            entity.Property(e => e.Tagline).IsUnicode(false);

            entity.Property(e => e.Title)
                .IsRequired()
                .IsUnicode(false);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<MoviesCompanies>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Property(e => e.CompanyId).HasColumnName("CompanyID");

            entity.Property(e => e.MovieId).HasColumnName("MovieID");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Company)
                .WithMany(p => p.MoviesCompanies)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.CompanyId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("FK__MoviesCom__Compa__398D8EEE");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Movie)
                .WithMany(p => p.MoviesCompanies)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.MovieId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("FK__MoviesCom__Movie__3A81B327");
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<MoviesCountries>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Property(e => e.Iso31661)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasColumnName("Iso_3166_1")
                .HasMaxLength(50)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            entity.Property(e => e.MovieId).HasColumnName("MovieID");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Iso31661Navigation)
                .WithMany(p => p.MoviesCountries)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.Iso31661)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("FK__MoviesCou__Iso_3__3F466844");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Movie)
                .WithMany(p => p.MoviesCountries)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.MovieId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("FK__MoviesCou__Movie__403A8C7D");
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<MoviesGenres>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Property(e => e.GenreId).HasColumnName("GenreID");

            entity.Property(e => e.MovieId).HasColumnName("MovieID");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Genre)
                .WithMany(p => p.MoviesGenres)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.GenreId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("FK__MoviesGen__Genre__3C69FB99");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Movie)
                .WithMany(p => p.MoviesGenres)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.MovieId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("FK__MoviesGen__Movie__3B75D760");
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<MoviesLanguages>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Property(e => e.Iso6391)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasColumnName("Iso_639_1")
                .HasMaxLength(50)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            entity.Property(e => e.MovieId).HasColumnName("MovieID");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Iso6391Navigation)
                .WithMany(p => p.MoviesLanguages)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.Iso6391)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("FK__MoviesLan__Iso_6__3E52440B");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Movie)
                .WithMany(p => p.MoviesLanguages)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.MovieId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("FK__MoviesLan__Movie__3D5E1FD2");
        });
    }
}
}
```

And the little Program.cs from the console app:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using MRA.DataAccessLayer_Core.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer;

namespace MRA.PresentationLayer_Console
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            mra_ss_dbContext _context = new mra_ss_dbContext();

            var list = _context.Movies.ToList();

            Console.WriteLine(list.Count);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

If anybody can help me, let me know!

Answer (score 0):

The solution for that issue is to add the package `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` and after that the `UseSqlServer` will appear after you add the using reference. I hope it works for anyone with that same issue as I had.